# Does the following conditions imply that $H$ is a subgroup?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $2^n$ under addition and $H$ be its subset of order $2^{n-1}$. Let there exist a $h\in H$ such that $$h+H=H$$ and this $h\neq 0$. Can we say that $H$ is a subgroup of $G?$

I know that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ if for all $h\in H$, $$h+H=H.$$So I am looking for a counter example in this regard. Please help.

Comment: Counterexample: G = {(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)}, H = {(1,0), (1,1)}, h = (0,1)

Comment: @ant Your $h$ isn't in $H$.

Comment: Do you assume that the group is abelian?

Comment: @AlanWang yes, it is abelian.

Comment: What happens if you take an element $h$ of order $2$ in $G$, and look at the preimage of a subset of $G/\langle h\rangle$ of order $|G|/4$ ($\langle h\rangle$ is normal in $G$ as $G$ is abelian)?

Comment: In $G=\Bbb F_2^4$, consider $$H=\{(1,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0),(1,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(1,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1),(1,0,0,1)\}$$ and $h=(1,0,0,0)$. We have $(0,1,0,0)+(0,0,1,0)\notin H$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio It is given that there exists a $h\in H$ such that $h+H=H$.

Comment: @MittalG Hence me writing $h=(1,0,0,0)$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio whoops, read it too quickly.
Okay what about G = Z/16, H = {0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 11}, h = 8?

Comment: @Ant I confirm that it works.